# Print line number when printing the contents from the ScintillaNet

Tags: c#, printing, line-numbers, scintilla, scintillanet

I'm trying to create an IDE using ScintillaNET and I'm using ScintillaNet as by editor, Is there a way to get the line numbers included with the ScintillaNet when I print my text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScintillaNet control has this [property](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/blob/f4a1be4df11580071b77dfe16b01893a738d1f03/src/ScintillaNET/Scintilla.cs#L4407):

```
public LineCollection Lines { get; }
```

You can iterate this collection and add the line numbers by this way:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ScintillaNET;

string _s=""; //The string where you will get the results
foreach (Line _l in scintilla1.Lines) //scintilla1 is the name of your ScintillaNet control
//Line is a class that represents an individual line of text and has several properties
{
    _s += "Line " + (_l.Index + 1).ToString() + ": " + _l.Text; 
}
MessageBox.Show(_s);
```

If you set the control with this text:

```
Bla, bla, bla 1 
Bla, bla, bla 2
Bla, bla, bla 3
Bla, bla, bla 4
```

You will get this result:

[image]